# Find files with a given mode and smaller than a specific size

Tags: unix

How can i list all files with a size less than 400 bytes and having the rights 644 ?

Comment: `find` can do this. Type `man find`

Answer (score 4):

```
find $directory_to_search -perm 644 -size 400c
```

should do the trick.

Comment: he wanted atmost 400 bytes so it should be -size -400c

Comment: Perhaps add `-type f`